# How do I exit this loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

My program is meant to search a multidimensional array for a state that the user inputs. Then it supplies the state bird and flower. However I can't figure out where I need to place the statement to exit the loop. It will continue to search the array for input and ask the question over and over like I want it to. But I've tried a few different methods and can't get it to exit the loop when I enter none.

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a State or None to exit: ");
    String stateName = userInput.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < stateInformation.length; i++) {
        if (stateInformation[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(stateName)) {
            System.out.println(stateInformation[i][0] + ":\n " +
                "The State bird is the " + stateInformation[i][1] + "\n " +
                "The State Flower is the " + stateInformation[i][2]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which of the loops are u trying to break out of, while() or for()

Comment: I was trying to break out of the while loop when the input "none" was received. @pmcevoy12 gave me exactly what I was looking for though. However, now I'm running into the problem that when I enter a 2 word state it takes me back to the prompt without any output for the state. I'm guessing my loop doesn't account for spaces or something, but I'm not sure where the hang up is.

Comment: To account for spaces, you could use the method nextLine() rather than the method next() of the Scanner class.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you use `break` on a specific statement of your choice:

```
myLabel:
while (true)
{
    while (true)
    {
        break myLabel; // This will break out of the outer loop that has been labeled.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to exit while loop. You should check what is user input before for-loop and if it's None, use break. Second option is to check if input is none in argument of while.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want to break out of the for loop, it will be fine if you use a function and then use return as shown below:

```html
private Object searchData(...) 
{
        for (Type t : types2) {
            if (some condition) {
                // Do something and break...
                return object;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program prompts the user to enter `None` to exit. So add a conditional to handle that behavior:

```
String stateName = userInput.nextLine();
if (stateName.equalsIgnoringCase("none")) {
  break;
}
```

This will terminate your `while (true)` loop.

As discussed in the comments, it's generally better to use [`Scanner.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) to capture user input.

Comment: yup this worked just like @pmcevoy12 recommendation did. I tried both because your syntax is different but I guess it means the same thing. No I notice though that the program goes directly back to the prompt when a 2 word state is entered. I'm guessing because I may not be accounting for the space, but I'm not sure how to do that either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Change ```userInput.next()``` to ```userInput.nextLine()```.The userInput variable is a ```Scanner```.  It uses ```next()``` for a space delimited String and ```nextLine()``` to read until a newline.

Comment: `"None".equals(stateName)` and `stateName.equals("None")` are equivalent as long as `stateName` isn't `null`. Putting the literal (`"None"`) first is a common "trick" to handle poorly-written code with possibly-null values. The more standard literal-last format is generally considered easier to read, but will trigger a `NullPointerException` if the variable is `null`. Since [`Scanner.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) doesn't return `null`s there's no need use the literal-first trick.

Comment: As @pmcevoy12 said, [`Scanner.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) reads a single token (roughly speaking, a single word), while [`Scanner.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) reads a full line. When working with user input you generally want to read a line at a time (thus `.nextLine()`) since the "Enter" key is generally used to "submit" input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check if the userInput is "None" and then break out of the while loop like this:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a State or None to exit: ");
    String stateName = userInput.next();
    if ("None".equalsIgnoreCase(stateName)) break; // Added to break the while loop

    for (int i = 0; i < stateInformation.length; i++) {
        if (stateInformation[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(stateName)) {
            System.out.println(stateInformation[i][0] + ":\n " +
                "The State bird is the " + stateInformation[i][1] + "\n " +
                "The State Flower is the " + stateInformation[i][2]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you!! This is exactly what i needed. I was close I was just putting it in the wrong area, usually after the for loop and kept getting the wrong results. I didn't think about placing the if statement right after the input but now it works perfectly.